# Where to store the datasets? - Session or Cache in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session, caching

freshly boarded the asp.net boat.

I have an asp.net page that initially displays some data in a gridview with pagination(with a dataset as its datasource). And, there are few textboxes to perform insertions or updations ( don't ask about the edit/insert options in the gridview itself!!).

I need few guidances regarding the right place to store datasets.

Im posting the simplified codebehind file, that uses viewstate to store the dataset, which I dont like.

```
enter code here

class xyx : Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
    GridBind();

    }

}
protected void InsertUpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 1.perform insert or update data in the database

 2.GridBind();


}
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.SelectedIndex = -1;
    GridView1.DataSource = (DataSet)ViewState["DataSet"];
    GridView1.DataBind();

}


private void GridBind()
{
     DataSet ds = getDataFromDataBase();
     GridwView1.DataSource = ds;
     GridView1.DataBind();
     ViewState["DataSet"] = ds;

}
}
```

Now apart from viewstate, what is the best choice to store the datasets??...

1. get the data from database everytime
2. Use a common Session variable Session["DataSet"] for all the datasets across all the pages(I have a few other pages with the same scenario )
3. Use Cache

I included session or cache because it is likely that the user might just be viewing the data rather than inserting or updating.

Also, In the Button click event instead of calling GridBind(), is it OK if I just updated the dataset in the viewstate rather than fetching data again from the database?

like -

```
  DataSet ds = ViewSate["DataSet"] (or) Session["DataSet"] (or) Cache["DataSet"]; 
  (perform updations or insertions upon the dataset)
  Session(or)Cache(or)ViewState["DataSet"] = ds;
```

Comment: possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011416/should-i-use-session-cache-to-store-the-dataset-or-should-i-fetch-fresh-from-the

Comment: Is it data that needs to be cached?

Comment: Yeah, The dataset!!!.....sarcasm??

Comment: @buzz hmm might be, but i gave a scenario. Its okay If i get straight answers which are short enuf, cause I gave the scenario and cases.

Comment: enuf to creep a developer to use viewstate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally:

- If the data must be up to date, fetch it every time
- If stale data is OK (or doesn't change often):

  - If the data is different per user, store in `Session`
  - If the data is the *same* for all users, use `Cache` or `Application`

If you wish to store **large amounts of data** per user **do not use Session** - you could run out of memory.

Comment: so, Its okay to store in session. but I hear lots of people saying session is evil.

Comment: @user1247808 - Because session is _per user_, you should only store small amounts of data in it. Over using it (with lots of data) means that your server will end up running out of memory very quickly.

Comment: session is better option ,only problem is that it expires after sometime

Comment: @user1247808: Oded has not said that it's ok to store it in session(or cache). He said it's ok if it doesn't change(often) and it's different for every user. But your app doesn't scale well when you store large datasets in memory. Consider that the number of users will increase in future. You also have to provide the locking yourself. I've asked a related question some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432393/dataset-in-cache-collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-might-not-execu

Comment: @AnkitKulshreshtha - You are making assumptions. It **might** be better, depending on usage scenario.

Comment: sorry!....my internet connection went down. anyways, data in my datasets in all the pages are different per users. So How about using a common session variable across all the pages?, that way it wont hog up the memory, but im worried about the frequent updations on the common session variable.

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon many condition you should take care of these things first

1. Number of records in dataset.
2. Number of users.

If there are thousand of record then fetch only those record required. User some pager control.
[here is an expample](http://dotnetsqltips.blogspot.in/2012/03/custom-paging-in-aspnet-gridview-using.html)

For better use of paging.